# Precision problem on AMD

Tags: hlsl, hardware, float

I have a problem with precision on AMD in shaders (`hlsl`). In vertex shader I calculate `UVs` for particle using modulus operator on float. With simple `%` there is a problem on Nvidia and on AMD (e.g. `7 % 7 = 7`) so I have written modulus as:

```
float Mod( float x, float y )    
{       
     return x - floor(x / y) * y;    
}
```

This have fixed the problem on Nvidia but AMD still returns wrong values.

Any idea what is going on? And how to fixed it?

I know I can use:

```
float( int( x ) % int( y ) )
```

but I think it is slower and I wonder if there is any better way.

Comment: Are you using DX or are you using vulkan?  Both support HLSL...

Comment: I'm using DirectX11

Answer (score 1):

In HLSL, you can use the built-in [`fmod`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509601(v=vs.85).aspx) function for this.

I'm not sure what's going wrong with your implementation, though. It looks mathematically correct. It's conceivable you're encountering a precision issue with the subtraction, depending on the inputs.

BTW, an alternative implementation which avoids the subtraction is:

```
float Mod(float x, float y)
{
    return frac(x / y) * y;
}
```

Comment: But `frac(x / y) * y` is exactly what normal modulus operator compiles to (on GCN at least) and it gives incorrect results on both Nvidia and AMD. I'm not sure about `fmod`, though. It seems to give slightly different assembly code. I will check it, thanks.

Comment: So I have chacked it and `frac(x / y) * y`, operator `%` and `fmod` give incorrect results on Nvidia and AMD. `x - floor(x / y) * y` works correct on Nvidia but AMD not so much.